# -igible, (suffix)

Tags: suffixes

negligible = able to be neglected

corrigible = able to be corrected

dirigible = able to be directed

eligible = able to be elected

Are there any other words following this pattern?

Comment: How many verbs are there that end in _-ect_? In adding the _-ible_ suffix, the final T drops, and the /k/ C voices between vowels, producing /g/ G. This was done in Latin a thousand years before English borrowed the words.

Comment: The suffix here is *-ible* — *-igible* is not a suffix. There are plenty of these, and they’re all colligible.

Comment: Right. Here's a selection, with optional prefixes: _(il)legible
(in/un)eligible
(non)negligible
(un/mis)intelligible
colligible
erigible
dirigible
(in/un)corrigible
(in)exigible
((ir)re)frangible
diffrangible
infrangible
(pre/in/un)tangible
(un)infringible
tingible
(non)fungible
(in)expungible
(un)submergible
(un)immersible
detergible_

Comment: @JohnLawler: isn't the voiced/voiceless alternation the other way around: the /g/ was devoiced in Latin to /k/ before the voiceless /t/? As far as I know, Latin did not turn intervocalic /k/ to /g/; with "induct," "deduct" and other words derived from *ducere*, we have "inducible" and "deducible."

Comment: Whatever. The point is there's several stems, and the voiced one appears intervocalically. The history isn't important.

Comment: @JohnLawler : In some of your examples I am uncertain of the correpsonding verb. Can you include those?  In the case of "exigible" I surmise that it may be "exact", but I'm not sure.

Comment: "Tangible" is clearly related to "tangent", from _tangere_.

Comment: Virtually all of them come from Latin, with the -_ibilis_ suffix already attached, so some of the roots it's attached to may not exist in English.

Comment: @JohnLawler : Why do you say "virtually all" rather than just "all".  Is there one among them that doesn't come from Latin?

Comment: @Michael: Because I didn't look all of them up, only most. Feel free to finish them off. Etymologies are easy to find on the Web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (in)corrigible
>   dirigible
>   erigible (able to be erected)
>   exigible (able to be charged)
>   (in)eligible
>   exigible (able to be required)
>   (un)intelligible
>   (non)negligible

Comment: intelligible - able to be intellected?

Comment: @immibis able to be understood.